# ajax realtime form validation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax for signup form with jquery blur, it is validating , but when i click on submit form data gets save in db 
i need not to save data on submit untill user not correct the fields text 
how can i avoid this problem ?

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#username').blur(function() {
var username = $('#username').val();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
      {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                if(username !=""){
                //$('#wait').removeClass('loading');

                    if(xmlhttp.responseText.match(/Space/g)){ 
                        $('#usernameErr').css('display','none');
                        $("#valid_username").html('User name is not valid');
                        $('#wait').addClass('loading'); 
                        return false;       
                    }
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText.match(/No/g)){ 
                        $('#usernameErr').css('display','none');
                        $("#valid_username").html('');
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
         // $('#wait').addClass('loading');
          xmlhttp.open("GET","process_signup.php?name="+username,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
```

});

Comment: You may want to use a plugin like [jQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) so that you can fire the validation on the ajax call and on form submit, this preventing submitting until the form is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form from submitting until the errors are cleared. You can do something like this:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(e){
    if( checkFormForErrors() ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Then just build a `checkFormForErrors` function and have it return true if there are any errors with the form.

However, keep in mind that you should **always** check for errors on the server side as well. Never assume the user is giving you good input. You will get hacked if you don't check the input.